# What will the graph of this parametric equation look like?

Tags: graphing-functions, parametric

What will the graph of this parametric equation look like?

$$x = 2t$$
$$y = t + 5, \quad -2 ≤ t ≤ 3$$

Does "$-2 ≤ t ≤ 3$" represent the domain?

Comment: There are a number of online tools that you can use to explore this sort of thing, like [WolframAlpha](http://goo.gl/0VnTj5).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it means that you will only consider values of $t$ ranging from $-2$ to $3$, although the expressions make sense for all $t$. Notice that $-2 \leq t \leq 3 \implies -4\leq 2t \leq 6$, that is, $-4 \leq x \leq 6$. Eliminating $t$ from these expressions, we obtain $$y = \frac{x}{2}+5,$$ a line segment in the plane, joining the points $(-4,3)$ and $(6,8)$.

Comment: So the graph will be the line of y = x/2 + 5.

Comment: That's what I have said. But remember that you won't be graphing it for all values of $x$. Just for some.

Comment: Woohoo! Thank you so much!

Comment: And yes, I understand that. That's where the domain comes into play, yes?

Comment: Exactly! ${}{}{}$

Comment: @SierraM, if your problem is solved, you can always accept one of the answers that you've got (you're not forced to, though), this way the question goes out of the unanswered list and the site keeps organized. If you still need any help, please say it :)

Comment: This doesn't have to do with graphing parametric equations, but it relates to parametrics. How do I eliminate the parameter of x = 3 cos t, y = 3 sin t?

Comment: One strategy is to write $y/x = \tan t,$ so that $t = \arctan(y/x)$, for $x \neq 0$. But note that $x^2+y^2 = 9$, so you've got a circle there. Usually it is easier to work with parametric equations in these cases.